# Declined pushing develop to remote master which is protected after build in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Remote master branch is protected which means least one approved review is required before merging.

So I want to merge develop branch to master after build. my jenkins's configurations of project are like this as below.

[image]

1. It will make local master branch is merged by develop branch in the workspace of jenkins server.
2. Build the project

[image]

3. If build is successful, the local master branch pushs to remote master branch.

**Console Error**

```
stderr: remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.        
remote: error: At least one approved review is required
```

How can I push local branch to protection branch of github? Should I release branch protection?

Comment: Push your development branch to github, open a Pull Request, get someone to approve it, and merge it into the protected branch.

Answer (score 0):

It is because protected branch doesn't allow force push. Just turn off the protection on that branch.

**OR**

```
git checkout -b <new_branch>
```

and

```
git push origin  <new_branch>
```

and waiting to  merge to master by own